# Can I use a regex expression to get a substring

Tags: regex

I have a excel file that has a CDFSDDRCxxxCurryymmdd.xls(x) where xxx is a number and yymmdd is a date.

I use this bit of code to get the Cxxx from the file name.

```
GetCompanyIdResult cmpId =
                    PantareiDataClasses.GetCompanyId(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name.Substring(7, 4)).FirstOrDefault();
```

And somewhere in my code I use this bit of code to check if the file has a correct name. So I was wondering if I could use a regex expression to find and retrieve the Cxxx from my file name instead of using string manipulation.

Is that possible?
Rui Martins

```
Match nameIsValid = Regex.Match(activeWorkbook.Name,
                                      @"CDFSDDRC(?<xxx>[0-9]+)Curr(?<yymmdd>[0-9][0-9][0|1][0-9][0-3][0-9])\.xls?");

                switch (nameIsValid.Success)
                {
                    case false:
                        throw new DdrFileNameFormatNotValid("DDR file has a wrong name format");
                }
```

Comment: Seems good. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex looks fine. Now you just need to extract the named capturing group, using `nameIsValid.Groups["xxx"].Value`:

```
string input = "CDFSDDRC123Curr120903.xls(x)";      
Match nameIsValid = Regex.Match(input, @"CDFSDDRC(?<xxx>[0-9]+)Curr(?<yymmdd>[0-9][0-9][0|1][0-9][0-3][0-9])\.xls?");
if (nameIsValid.Success) {
  string key = nameIsValid.Groups["xxx"].Value;
  Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```

To extract the date part, use `nameIsValid.Groups["yymmdd"].Value` instead.

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/mplfn)**.